# How to import ods file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to import an .ods file. I choose the file from the file chooser and OpenDocument Spreadsheet is selected automatically in the format dropdown. I click go.

It gives me error:

You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/zip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

Why am I getting this error? How can I import it?

Comment: you can't import `ods` file! first in your spreadsheet export data as `CSV` file and then try to import

Comment: There is a spreadsheet option apart from csv in the format menu. What makes you say I can't?

Comment: I have quotes and commas withing the data, csv is not really handy. I've had lots of problems with it so far and importing directly from spreadsheet works out much more cleaner.

Comment: oh,, didn't know there is option for that now, I guess I'm not up to date :) I've used `CSV` for most of importing in past projects